# in NSCollectionView, the SelectItems function does not trigger ItemSelected in delegate

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, nscollectionview

OS is 10.13. In an NSCollectionView, when I call "DeselectAll" programmatically, ItemSelected is called in the delegate. However, when I call "SelectItems", even though the item gets selected, ItemSelected is not called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectItems(at:scrollPosition) will not call the delegate methods by design. See Apple documentation for the method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1525656-selectitems

Michael

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe it is a bug. I had to override SelectItems and manually add the call to ItemsSelected.

```
public override void SelectItems(NSSet indexPaths, NSCollectionViewScrollPosition scrollPosition)
{
      base.SelectItems(indexPaths, scrollPosition);
      Delegate.ItemsSelected(this, indexPaths);
}
```

Comment: Wait, this is not a link only answer. This is the answer!